# How to prove a number is a Multiple of an integer in MatLab?

Tags: matlab

How can we prove a number if it is really a multiple or divisible by an integer, WITHOUT using mod() and -rem() in MATLAB?

Comment: Is this homework? Seems like a pretty arbitrary and pointless restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ROUND`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/round.html):

```
% To determine if i0 is a multiple of i1:
is_multiple = ( i1 * round(double(i0)/i1) == i0 );
```

Comment: If you're using floating point for the division, rounding would be better than floor or ceil. If `i0` is a multiple of `i1` and sufficiently large, the conversion to `double` will change its value, and the quotient may be a little smaller or larger than the actual integer quotient. In each case, one of `floor` and `ceil` would fail.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Updated to reflect your concern.  I'm not sure if this is currently an actual issue, though.  Matlab (R2010b, at least)  limits integer division to 32-bit integers.  I've tested the ceil approach with INT_MAX('int32')-2 (2147483645, which is divisible by 5), and things seem okay.  Not exactly an exhaustive test, though, and round works just as well as ceil or floor.

Comment: Why not use integer division for this?

Comment: @BrianL Matlab is heavily weighted toward floating point numbers. It gets finicky about combining integers that aren't the same class. I'm also not sure how [`IDIVIDE`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/idivide.html) is implemented, but the myriad rounding options suggest that it may be implemented with doubles internally.

Answer (score 0):

use `factor`, if the result is just 1 and the original number, then it's a prime.

Or simply use `isprime`